# Sql queries not 'reporting' back until all queries have finish executing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running a set of sql queries and they are not reporting the row affect until all the queries have ran. Is there anyway i can get incremental feedback.

Example:

```
   DECLARE @HowManyLastTime int

SET @HowManyLastTime = 1

WHILE @HowManyLastTime <> 2400000
 BEGIN

      SET @HowManyLastTime = @HowManyLastTime +1
    print(@HowManyLastTime)
 END
```

This doesn't show the count till the loop has finished. How do i make it show the count as it runs?

Comment: Your query shows the count as it runs in the messages tab when I run it on sql2008.

Comment: Are/Can you put `GO` between your statements? If you put a GO in though, your variables will fall out of scope so be careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To flush recordcounts and other data to the client, you'll want to use RaisError with NOWAIT. Related questions and links:

- [PRINT statement in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268384/print-statement-in-t-sql)
- http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/10/01/SQL-Server-Notify-client-of-progress-in-a-long-running.aspx

In SSMS this will work as expected. With other clients, you might not get a response from the **client** until the query execution is complete.

Comment: I tried `RAISERROR ('Your message', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT` but that still has the same behviour

Comment: What client are you using? Is this from your application (eg ASP.Net), or SSMS, or some other environment?

Comment: If you're using SSMS, is it possible that your UI is set to "Results to Grid" and you're just not switching to the "Messages" tab in the UI? (if there are no resultsets, SSMS switches to the "Messages" tab automatically when the query completes, but not before)

Answer (score 0):

SQL tends to be 'set-based', and you are thinking procedurally and trying to make it act systematically. It really doesn't make sense to do this in SQL.

I would be asking you motivation for doing this, and is there anything better that can be tried.