# SQL Server output param truncated where it is too long

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, output

I have 4 stored procedures.

The following is used to be invoked by C#:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_retrieveResourceShell]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(MAX)

    EXEC    [dbo].[sp_retrieveResTree]
            @pid = NULL,
            @ret = @result OUTPUT

    ***select*** @result 
END
```

These are internal stored procedures:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_retrieveResTree]
    (@pid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
     @ret NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @mdlId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
            @mdlGroup NVARCHAR(MAX)
        
    DECLARE mdlCursor CURSOR FOR
        ......

    DECLARE @subRet NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @viewRet NVARCHAR(MAX)

    EXEC [dbo].[sp_retrieveResTree]
            @pid = @mdlId,
            @ret = @subRet OUTPUT

    EXEC dbo.sp_retrieveResView
            @mdlId = @mdlId,
            @ret = @viewRet OUTPUT

     SET @mdlGroup = @mdlGroup + FORMATMESSAGE('{"Id":"%s","Name":"%s","Subs":%s,"Views":%s},'...)
    .......

   SET @ret = FORMATMESSAGE('[%s]',@mdlGroup)
END

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_retrieveResView]
    (@mdlId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
     @ret NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
   SET @ret = FORMATMESSAGE('[%s]',@viewGroup)
END
```

When I invoke `sp_retrieveResourceShell` like this:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_retrieveResourceShell]

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

I can get a truncated string with ellipsis at the string tail.
how to get the full string without ellipsis?

---

***update***

Changed formatmessage function to string concatenation likes

```
SET @mdlGroup = @mdlGroup + '{"Id":"' + CAST(@mdlId AS CHAR(36))+ '","Name":"' + @mdlName + '","Subs":' + @subRet + ',"Views":' + @viewRet +'},'
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: _I can get a truncated string with ellipsis at the string tail._ Are you talking about the print output from `sp_retrieveResourceShell`? Since print output isn't part of a result set it's really up to the client as to what happens with it - most clients don't even show it at all by default.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print VARCHAR(MAX) using Print Statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850477/how-to-print-varcharmax-using-print-statement)

Comment: FORMATMESSAGE is documented to do this for strings longer than 2048 chars. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/formatmessage-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, in fact , i used "SELECT @result" , not "print @result"

Comment: thanks  @MartinSmith. it's very helpful .  i have changed FORMATMESSAGE  to string concatenation. and the result now can hold 4448 unicode characters, and it was still not the full string yet.

Comment: You need to debug where it is getting truncated then and check string sizes at various points with DATALENGTH

Comment: @MartinSmith , thanks for the reply. i tried as you said, and found when the string length using "DATALENGTH(@mdlGroup)" long than 8000 , then it was truncated.

Comment: This is being caused by the `PRINT` statement, it has an output limit on SSMS.

Comment: Why use `FORMATMESSAGE` when you can use proper `FOR JSON`? Why use `PRINT` when you can use `SELECT`?

Comment: @Charlieface, the data base is SQL Server 2012 R2, not SQL Server 2016 or later .  print ?  no , actually i used Select . see comment before.

Comment: `sp_retrieveResourceShell` has a `PRINT` statement, and does not `SELECT` it, so not sure what you mean. Have you considered upgrading to a supported version?

Comment: @Charlieface,  I made a update , change "print" to "select" , and this problem has been solved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PRINT statement in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268384/print-statement-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 1):

when using string concatenation , likes

```
SET @ret = N'[' + @mdlGroup + N']'
```

and refernce to [[n]varchar(max) + [n]varchar(max)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12639972/1814688)

i got the right full string . Thanks to @MartinSmith at the same time .